# Manifest JSON 404 (Not Found) on Ionic CLI : 6.6.0

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic

**console on chrome**

*Likewise failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.*

He añadido manualmente un manifest.json  en ionic esto no trabaja bien. Esto está pasando
en locally(localhost..). Asimismo cuando instalo la app en una table o android mobile, esta no instala el icon para móvil debido al err del manifest.json.

```
    {
        "name": "Name",
        "short_name": "Name",
        "description": "description",
        "icons": [
            {
                "src": "assets/icons/x_48x48.png",
                "sizes": "48x48",
                "type": "image/png"
            }
        ],
        "start_url": "/",
        "background_color": "#ff6600",
        "display": "standalone",
        "theme_color": "#ff6600"
    }
```

---

**Solventado**

Tú necesitas hacer todo desde el archivo config.xlm.

Comment: No deberias cambiar el manifest a mano para poder meter por ejemplo un icono diferente a la app, para eso existe el comando ionic resources, te recomiendo que para solucionar el error que tienes digites en la terminal donde tienes el proyecto ionic repair --cordova. Tal vez funcione

Comment: Solventado.

Tú necesitas hacer todo desde el archivo config.xlm.